# In App purchase, can I use originalTransaction property to discriminate transaction is "Restored" or not?

Tags: in-app-purchase

```
    if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
    }
    else if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased){
    }
```

Apple alert comes as " You have already purchased this item, Tap ok to download"but the SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored is not called, the state is still "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased", so these codes are not working.

I think "originalTransaction" maybe can help me, here is my code below:

```
    SKPaymentTransaction *trans = transaction.originalTransaction;

    if (trans) {
        // restored transaction
    }
    else{
        // not restored transaction, purchased?
    }
```

Are these codes reliable ? Thanks.

Comment: I do the same check whether transaction was restored or not.